# Remove multiple users from multiple Teams if NOT in csv

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a script which adds users to Teams from a .csv, but there are likely to be additions/removals which will need to be accounted for in the first weeks after creation.

```
# Read team users from CSV file
$TeamUsers = Import-CSV "File_Path"
$i = 0

# Group the objects by their TeamDesc property, so we only query each group once
$TeamUsers | Group-Object TeamDesc | ForEach-Object {
    # Get the GroupId of this Group
    $groupId = (Get-Team -DisplayName $_.Name).GroupId
  
  # If the Group couldn't be found, just skip below logic
    if(-not $groupId) { return }
  
  # If the Group could be found, create a hashtable for future splatting
    $params = @{ GroupId = $groupId }
    
    # now we can enumerate each object in each group of objects
    foreach($user in $_.Group) {
        try {
            # create a hashtable for splatting progress
            $progress = @{
                PercentComplete = $i++ / $TeamUsers.Count * 100
                Activity        = 'Adding Users to MS Teams!!'
                Status          = 'Working on Team: "{0}" and User: "{1}"' -f $_.Name, $user.UserPrincipleName
            }
            Write-Progress @progress

            # add this user with this role to the hashtable
            $params['User'] = $user.UserPrincipleName
            $params['Role'] = $user.Role
            Add-TeamUser @params
        }
        catch {
            ('Error occurred for {0} - {1}' -f $user.TeamName, $user.UserPrincipleName),
            $_.ToString() | Write-Warning
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I can add users to the Team by adding their user information to the .csv but I want to be able to remove users if they are not found in the file. I found, in another answer, this selection:

```
    $validUsers   = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | Select-Object -Expand dn

    $invalidUsers = Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' |
            Where-Object { $validUsers -notcontains $_.distinguishedName }

    Remove-ADGroupMember 'groupname' $invalidUsers -WhatIf
```

I am unsure of the best way to include this. Where in my current script can I incorporate checking for and removing users NOT found in a .csv from the populated Teams?

Comment: The first script is adding users to a team and the second script is removing AD Objects from an AD group. Are you sure the second script shouldn't be using `Remove-TeamUser` ?

Comment: Can you check with using Remove-TeamUser?

Comment: That would probably work better. I only included the second because it looked closest to what I was looking for. 
My main concern is that this should all be automated. I will be given a list of users to add to multiple Teams, and reference the GroupId by looking it up by the Team names. 1-2 weeks later, I will be given a second list with some new additions and some original members dropped. I want to be able to use my second list of members to remove any existing Teams members NOT found in the updated csv. It would also need to reference GroupId by Team name as it does in the addition script.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below logic:

```
[array]$teams = "T1","T2","T3"
$users = gc C:\temp\UserList.txt

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $user = ($user -split "@")[0] # SamAccountName from UPN
    foreach($t in $teams) {
        $tMems = Get-AdGroupMember $t |select -exp SamAccountName
        if ($tMems -match $user) {
            RemoveAdGroupMember $t $user
        }
    }
}
```